# Save search results to spreadsheet

Tags: windows-home-server, file-search

I have a Windows Home Server with about 5,000 files that were corrupted and lost from multiple  a hard drive failure.
Before I blow them away so they're not included in future backups I want to get a listing of them.

How can I save a listing of all files with the *.wlx extension sitting on a \server\photos share? Can I export that list to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a command prompt (cmd from RUN) do a

```
cd\server\photos
dir *.wlx > corrupt.txt
```

That will output all those filenames to corrupt.txt in that same folder.

Comment: Your command helped but only got the root directory. Powershell offered me a little more nuance.

What ended up helping me the most was this command:
Get-ChildItem -recurse \server\photos -include *.wlx > corrupt

Comment: @JNK forgot the `/s` parameter to `dir`, but PowerShell is better, of course.